# POST with koa (nodejs)

Tags: node.js, post, koa, koa-router

I keep annoyingly on finding examples that only parse JSON sent. I am trying to find an example where a POST comes from a form.

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="/" method="post">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="your@email.here">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="password">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Sign in</button>
</form>
```

As you can see i have fields `email` and `password`. I am using `koa-router` which boasts express style routing but this isn't working:

```
.post('/', function* () {
    console.log(this.body.email); // <--- undefined
    console.log(this.body.password);
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use a library like the following:

https://github.com/cojs/co-body

```
let parse = require('co-body');

.post('/', function *(){
  let data = yield parse(this);
  console.log(data.email);
  console.log(data.password);
});
```